# iOS - CALayer protruding bounds on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints, calayer

I have a simple `CustomView`. I have a `CAGradientLayer` that I am adding to the `layer`.

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {
    
    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]

        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Below is the `Storyboard` setup

[image]

Below is the result in portrait on iPad, which is fine.

[image]

When the device orientation is changed, the layer of the `CustomView` is protruded from its bounds.

[image]

When I checked the view hierarchy in Xcode, the frame of the `CustomView` is adjusted accordingly, but, it is the layer which is protruding. To cross check, I removed all codes in `setupView` and set only a background colour, on orientation change, `CustomView` is adjusted as expected. But, why does it happen for layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting a new layer each time when `layoutSubviews` method call. That means it shows the line of the first layer.

Just update the frame from `layoutSubviews` and call setup method from `awakeFromNib`.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    private let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradient.frame = bounds
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
        
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```